# Android SQLiteDatabase WHERE selection

Tags: android, sqlite, where-clause

I used an online note taking tutorial to make notes. It works, but I want to make notes based on selection. I thought I did it right, but can someone explain to me what I am doing wrong? I am passing in the course code and I thought I set it up to select correctly. Just tell me what I need to do.

This code seems to be the problem. If selectionargs and where are null it works by returning all notes. I want to return all notes with the where statement to be WHERE courseCode = thisCourse.getCourseID() How do I do this?

(DBOpenHelper.NOTE_COURSE is courseCode)

```
@Override
public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {
    String whereClause = DBOpenHelper.NOTE_COURSE+"=?";
    String[] selectionArgs = { thisCourse.getCourseID().trim() };
    return new CursorLoader(this, NotesProvider.CONTENT_URI, null, whereClause, selectionArgs, null);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> If selectionargs and where are null it works by returning all notes

If you want to select rows from your table where `NOTE_COURSE` is null you must use `IS NULL`:

```
String whereClause = DBOpenHelper.NOTE_COURSE + " IS NULL";
```

NOTE: it is NOT an argument value!

**EDIT**

Where clause is used to **limit** returned data and as such it is **optional** and if no special where clause is specified then all rows match the query. This is what happen when you pass `null` because you simply tell "I do not want rows filered", so all rows are returned.

Also your code looks fine, however I am not sure what you call `trim()` for setting up `selectionArgs`.

Comment: I mean when I use null in the function CursorLoader parameters as opposed to calling selectionArgs and whereClause it returns all notes. I.E. `return new CursorLoader(this, NotesProvider.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);` I want to add a where identity and I don't know how to do that in the CursorLoader constructor.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is simple and it makes me feel so very silly. You need to make your parameters SQL ready by adding single quotes around them as seen in this example.

```
 @Override
public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {
    String whereClause = DBOpenHelper.NOTE_COURSE+" LIKE " + "'"+thisCourse.getCourseID()+"'";
    return new CursorLoader(this, NotesProvider.CONTENT_URI, null, whereClause, null, null);
}
```